# How do I undo a MySQL PAGER setting that hides sleeping processes like `\P grep -v Sleep`?

Tags: mysql, grep, pager, my.cnf

I [came across](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/show-processlist.html) this fancy way to [hide sleeping processes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/show-processlist.html) from `show processlist;`

```
mysql> \P grep -v Sleep
```

But how do I reverse this?

Comment: I had no idea how to do this before you asked your question. I googled _mysql pager_, went to the first page that it found, and the answer was right there. Did you make any attempt to find this yourself before asking?

Comment: Until I asked the question I didn't know that it was called "MySQL pager"

Answer (score 6):

From the MySQL [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-commands.html), also shown by the `help` command:

> nopager   (\n) Disable pager, print to stdout.